# Есть ли программа для автоматической (пакетной) установки расширений Chrome?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Существуют программы-оболочки (например **WPI**, **MInstall**) которые позволяют в автоматическом режиме установить пакет программ на компьютер. Администраторы создают свои сборки - подготавливают дистрибутивы программ, составляют описание, прописывают команды запуска с ключами.

Одна из основных программ на компьютере это браузер. Так например, Google Chrome "из коробки" предлагает лишь базовые возможности сёрфинга. Именно поэтому существует механизм добавления функционала и персонализации с помощью расширений и тем оформления.

Я, как системный администратор, подготавливая компьютеры для пользователей, после установки ОС и программ, также устанавливаю некоторые важные и нужные расширения для браузера. Раньше делал это вручную, сейчас написал небольшой скрипт (CMD), который через реестр указывает установить расширения.

Возможно кем-то написана программа, имеющая графический интерфейс для установки расширений браузера? Было бы удобно составить свой список расширений, а затем при обслуживании очередного компьютера просто расставить галочки напротив нужных и установить всё вместе из WebStore.

Comment: Я решил данную проблему просто раскатываним готового образа ОС, в который заранее поставил нужный софт и расширения.